# magento 1.6.1 - one page checkout - paypal payments pro - stuck on step 5

Tags: magento

I have enabled Paypal payments pro on Magento and after adding card details in step 5 of the one page checkout the continue button does not work. I have also tried running the associated javascript function payment.save() in console without success.

The continue button works if I select the normal paypal express option which redirects the user to the paypal login.

I've been looking through the associated javascript library /skin/frontend/em006/default/js/opcheckout.js and at the payment.save() function but can't see anything obvious that might be causing the problem.

Anyone got any ideas?

Here is the payment function:

```
// payment
var Payment = Class.create();
Payment.prototype = {
beforeInitFunc:$H({}),
afterInitFunc:$H({}),
beforeValidateFunc:$H({}),
afterValidateFunc:$H({}),
initialize: function(form, saveUrl){
    this.form = form;
    this.saveUrl = saveUrl;
    this.onSave = this.nextStep.bindAsEventListener(this);
    this.onComplete = this.resetLoadWaiting.bindAsEventListener(this);
},

addBeforeInitFunction : function(code, func) {
    this.beforeInitFunc.set(code, func);
},

beforeInit : function() {
    (this.beforeInitFunc).each(function(init){
       (init.value)();;
    });
},

init : function () {
    this.beforeInit();
    var elements = Form.getElements(this.form);
    if ($(this.form)) {
        $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.bind(this));
    }
    var method = null;
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                method = elements[i].value;
            }
        } else {
            elements[i].disabled = true;
        }
        elements[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
    }
    if (method) this.switchMethod(method);
    this.afterInit();
},

addAfterInitFunction : function(code, func) {
    this.afterInitFunc.set(code, func);
},

afterInit : function() {
    (this.afterInitFunc).each(function(init){
        (init.value)();
    });
},

switchMethod: function(method){
    if (this.currentMethod && $('payment_form_'+this.currentMethod)) {
        var form = $('payment_form_'+this.currentMethod);
        form.style.display = 'none';
        var elements = form.select('input', 'select', 'textarea');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
    if ($('payment_form_'+method)){
        var form = $('payment_form_'+method);
        form.style.display = '';
        var elements = form.select('input', 'select', 'textarea');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) elements[i].disabled = false;
    }
    this.currentMethod = method;
},

addBeforeValidateFunction : function(code, func) {
    this.beforeValidateFunc.set(code, func);
},

beforeValidate : function() {
    var validateResult = true;
    var hasValidation = false;
    (this.beforeValidateFunc).each(function(validate){
        hasValidation = true;
        if ((validate.value)() == false) {
            validateResult = false;
        }
    }.bind(this));
    if (!hasValidation) {
        validateResult = false;
    }
    return validateResult;
},

validate: function() {
    var result = this.beforeValidate();
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }
    var methods = document.getElementsByName('payment[method]');
    if (methods.length==0) {
        alert(Translator.translate('Your order can not be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available for it.'));
        return false;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
        if (methods[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    result = this.afterValidate();
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }
    alert(Translator.translate('Please specify payment method.'));
    return false;
},

addAfterValidateFunction : function(code, func) {
    this.afterValidateFunc.set(code, func);
},

afterValidate : function() {
    var validateResult = true;
    var hasValidation = false;
    (this.afterValidateFunc).each(function(validate){
        hasValidation = true;
        if ((validate.value)() == false) {
            validateResult = false;
        }
    }.bind(this));
    if (!hasValidation) {
        validateResult = false;
    }
    return validateResult;
},

save: function(){
    if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
    console.log(checkout.loadWaiting);
    var validator = new Validation(this.form);
    if (this.validate() && validator.validate()) {
        checkout.setLoadWaiting('payment');
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveUrl,
            {
                method:'post',
                onComplete: this.onComplete,
                onSuccess: this.onSave,
                onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)
            }
        );
        console.log('run');
    }
    else {

        console.log('failed');
    }
},

resetLoadWaiting: function(){
    checkout.setLoadWaiting(false);
},

nextStep: function(transport){
    if (transport && transport.responseText){
        try{
            response = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')');
        }
        catch (e) {
            response = {};
        }
    }
    /*
    * if there is an error in payment, need to show error message
    */
    if (response.error) {
        if (response.fields) {
            var fields = response.fields.split(',');
            for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
                var field = null;
                if (field = $(fields[i])) {
                    Validation.ajaxError(field, response.error);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        alert(response.error);
        return;
    }

    checkout.setStepResponse(response);

    //checkout.setPayment();
},

initWhatIsCvvListeners: function(){
    $$('.cvv-what-is-this').each(function(element){
        Event.observe(element, 'click', toggleToolTip);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem (I think) are you using paypal payments pro hosted?  For me step 5 is review and the function that is not firing is review.save

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug for IE9 in Magento.  You don't mention what browser you are using but we have to make sure to include this tag on all of our Magento sites.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

See: http://alanstorm.com/ie9_fix_for_magento

Comment: Thanks for the tip Gordon, I am using firefox but I will include this anyway.

Any ideas what the problem would be now?